# модификаторы доступа при наследовании

Tags: c#, .net, ооп, наследование

какой модификатор доступа поможет в такой ситуации? нужно чтобы: поле НЕ передавалось наследнику, НО вызывалось у своего объекта.. это вообще  возможно?

Comment: пример добавьте, со слов выглядит как private. Объясните, зачем это все, кажется вы хотите странного.

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, это невозможно. У наследника должны быть все те же поля, что и у базового класса. Важным принципом наследования является принцип подстановки Барбары Лисков: объект-наследник __всегда__ можно использовать там же, где и базовый объект.

Иначе вам нужно не наследование, а что-то другое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модификаторов доступа не так много

В порядке расширения доступа:

```
private
protected
internal
public
```

- `private` - доступно только в рамках текущего класса
- `protected` - доступно в рамках класса и всем наследникам
- `internal` - доступно в рамках текущей сборки
- `public` - доступно всем

Сделать что-то типа `public` для сторонних классов, но `private` для наследников не имеет никакого смысла. Не может быть такого, что все могут использовать, а наследники - нет.

Больше информации: [Модификаторы доступа C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/access-modifiers).

Comment: да но я не так хочу...  мне нужно одно  поле класса ограничить  только Сабой, т.е чтобы он работал и внутри класса, и с своим объекта ....а другое сделать доступным и внутри  своего класса, и    и своему объекту и классу наследнику, и объекту наследника

Comment: но как я понял это невозможно...

Comment: @GiorgiTamazashvili скорее всего так и есть, если ответ был полезен, вы знаете что делать